# Image not show on web browser

Tags: javascript, c#, image, web, bitmap

I'm using a web-service in my website's server (c#) to get images as byte arrays and using the Bitmap class I'm saving them as .bmp files. For some reason, some of the files are not shown in the browser (chrome or IE), but are shown when opening them using any image displayer. I also tried saving the images as .png or .jpeg and got the same result - the same pictures were shown/not shown by the browser. 
What's really confuses me is that if I'm trying to open them using their local URI (c:/...) the browser shows them, but if I'm trying to use a their URL via the IIS manager (h**p://...) or dragging the image into the browser it doesn't show them.

Not sure what the problem may be because the data I'm receiving seems to be good since I can create and save a Bitmap object from it and also open it in image displayers such as windows gallery.

Is it possible that some of the images contain additional data that is not supported by browsers?

Any ideas as to how to handle this issue?

Comment: Is the content-type set correctly, or maybe the mime-types?

Comment: If your application is running on localhost you can see the local image. But the remote server cannot reach your local files. You have to upload them to the server. So, if the image file is not located inside your IIS website root folder, you cannot see it.